# Controller refuses to return 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017

**How do I force my controller to return a 404?**

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("account({accountid})/printgroup", Name = "Get")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int accountid)
        {
            var query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
            var uri = new Uri(Client.Instance.BaseAddress.ToString().Replace("[accountid]", accountid.ToString()) + query);
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage {RequestUri = uri, Method = HttpMethod.Get};
            var clientResponse = Client.Instance.SendAsync(request).Result;
            return clientResponse;
        }
```

When the `clientResponse` is 404, **the method does not return a response**. It just times out.

**What am I doing wrong? How do I force it to return a 404 if the client response is 404?**

EDIT:

Per macceturra's helpful comments, I've created my own object:

[image]

Yet the behavior is the same! The method will go out of scope, yet the client does not see anything. It just times out.

**My latest update is:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("account({accountid})/bill({billingRunId})", Name = "GetInvoiceSummary")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetInvoiceSummary(int accountid, int billingRunId)
    {
        var query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
        var uri = new Uri(Client.Instance.BaseAddress.ToString() + accountid + "/" + billingRunId + query);
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = uri, Method = HttpMethod.Get };
        var response = await Client.Instance.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            return NotFound();

        return ResponseMessage(response);

    }
```

The behavior is once again the same.

Comment: Why are you trying to return the `HttpResponse` of another request as your own response?

Comment: You aren't throwing a 404 anywhere.  The WebApi does not care that a property of HttpResponseMessage is = 404.  It just serializes the object and returns it to the caller. You should check the response, throw a `new HttpNotFoundException()` if the response from your call is a 404.  I would add that it seems like a bad idea to return HttpResonseMessage and not the actual object you want/need.  Also you are blocking the thread by not awaiting the async call.

Comment: @maccettura why would i need to await the call?

Comment: Your code is not asynchronous until you do.

Comment: @maccettura i dont need it to be async

Comment: "You should check the response, throw a new HttpNotFoundException() if the response from your call is a 404." ------ is this the standard practice? can i simply new up an httpresponsemessage and return the content and statuscode from the previous one?

Comment: WebApi is serializing the objects you are returning.  It does not care what it is serializing.  Having a `clientResponse` variable that contains some property to indicate a `404` means nothing to WebApi.  If you want your call to return a `404` you have to either roll your own 404 response, or let the framework handle it for you by throwing an `HttpNotFoundException()`.  Typically you wouldnt return the built in .NET classes from your WebApi, you would return custom classes that represent your data (like the `Result` property of your `clientResponse` object).

Comment: @maccettura thank you very much for yoru help. i've updated my question with an animated gif (give it like 10 seconds if you dont see any movement), i partially followed your advice and created a response; i am just baffled why even when i return a new HttpResponseMessage, it will not return! i will now create my own object to return

Comment: i've also tried: return Request.CreateResponse(clientResponse.StatusCode, clientResponse.Content);  -- again same behavior

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you call `.Result` on a `Task<T>` then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @mason whats your source?

Comment: It can cause deadlocks. Refer to [async best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Whether or not you want async code, you are using async code (incorrectly) and you need to fix it.

Comment: HttpClient has no non-async method to retrieve data, what am i to do?

Comment: Either pick a library that exposes non-async methods, or asyncify your action method. Should be easy. Add the async keyword, set the return type to `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` and await the results of your async call.

Comment: @mason i've made the suggested changes, though the behavior is the same: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ZjDj31QqjVw/WYtIgqPC66I/AAAAAAAADag/ZqABquJTh60XYGINBhxnXRZJa2YBuzzzwCHMYCw/s0/devenv_2017-08-09_12-38-10.png

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your error. I said it's something you need to do to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @mason this worked, though i am still vulnerable to deadlock https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-SirIfaxT0Hk/WYtKP3GOmII/AAAAAAAADaw/GOjXGobj92Q918vr0BxQY2Jli7c8ypkQwCHMYCw/s0/devenv_2017-08-09_12-45-34.png

Comment: So why not fix the potential deadlock issue?

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' you may have misunderstood what I was trying to say.  I dont mean create a new `HttpResponseMessage`,  I mean create a class that encompasses the data you wish to return from your API endpoint. You also want to throw a HttpNotFoundException if you wish to get a 404 returned from your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Update**

Based on discussion in comments it was advised that you review the response pipeline as it was determined that the code in the action was handling/executing the request as intended. The issue was being encountered by the response on its way out the pipeline which cause the client to time out. Check your message handlers and middle-ware in the pipeline that may be causing the response to block on its way out the pipeline based on how it was handled by your controllers.

---

### Original answer

Consider the following, using the preferred Web API 2.* syntax along with proper use of async/await.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("account({accountid})/printgroup", Name = "Get")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(int accountid) {
    var query = Request.RequestUri.Query;
    var uri = new Uri(Client.Instance.BaseAddress.ToString().Replace("[accountid]", accountid.ToString()) + query);
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = uri, Method = HttpMethod.Get };
    var clientResponse = await Client.Instance.SendAsync(request);
    if (clientResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        return NotFound();

    return ResponseMessage(clientResponse);
}
```

Comment: i was certain this would solve this issue, but it made no difference: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-vKGL-nbZ_YI/WYuv_DcYjQI/AAAAAAAADbY/czlFjqsOyDgIAa-op4mJQO--ox1WyddjgCHMYCw/s0/2017-08-09_19-59-11.gif

Comment: Ok most odd. To trouble shoot. Try this test please. Remove everything from that action and just return `NotFount()` and see if the same Issue arises. If it does then the problem is outside of the code being executed. There is a bottleneck somewhere in the pipeline on the messages way out.

Comment: did exactly as you had suggested: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-4UAgXY0ZnvI/WYuyVBBy54I/AAAAAAAADbg/ckB-rgjfq1EtC23PTyl4DA3jzkw8Qb9GQCHMYCw/s0/2017-08-09_20-08-05.gif

Comment: Change method signature to just `IHttpActionResult`. Remove the `async Task`.

Comment: But outside of that you have a problem in the web api pipeline. nothing wrong with your code. there is a deadlock in the pipeline on the way out

Comment: Are you using any custom message handler or middle ware. I would suggest you start there.

Answer (score 1):

After adding this piece of middleware, the problem has been resolved:

```
public class NotFoundMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public NotFoundMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound
            && !context.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-ServiceFabric")
        )
            context.Response.Headers.Add("X-ServiceFabric", new[] { "ResourceNotFound" });
    }
}
```

Comment: So from this I  gather that the problem originated with service fabric not knowing how to handle `Not Found` responses which caused gateway timeouts.